# How to output CSV from multidimensional array, when sub array might have unique key pair?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

My googlefoo has failed me.
Given this array:

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => abc123
            [price] => 19.95
            [special_price] => 0
            [tier20] => 13.48
            [tier40] => 16.98
            [tier50] => 17.48

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => def456
            [price] => 129.98
            [special_price] => 79.98
            [tier50] => 123.48
            [tier100] => 116.98
            [tier250] => 110.48
        )
```

The first 3 key->values will be the same between all elements (~2500 or so), but the last 3 there could be several dozen of total.

I need to generate a CSV file from this, where each sub-array (product) is a line, and each key gets a column? I specifically need each [tierX] to have a unique column.

Comment: So what is the expected output format? CSV can be any format. Also what have you tried? Just saying you tried googling is not enough

Comment: My problem is that that the output by default does not give the tiers s a unique column. I need the output like this:

`sku, price, special_price, tier20, tier40, tier50, tier100, tier200, etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first find all possible tiers then loop the array again to build a table array.
There are comments in code to explain most of the code.

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sku' => 'abc123',
    'price' => '19.95',
    'special_price' => '0',
    'tier20' => '13.48',
    'tier40' => '16.98',
    'tier50' => '17.48',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'sku' => 'def456',
    'price' => '129.98',
    'special_price' => '79.98',
    'tier50' => '123.48',
    'tier100' => '116.98',
    'tier250' => '110.48',
  ),
);

//Find all possible tiers 
$tier =[];
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $tier = array_merge($tier, preg_grep("/(tier.*)/", array_keys($sub)));
}
//Unique tiers
$tier = array_unique($tier);

//Count tiers
$columns = count($tier);

//Header of CSV with tiers
$header = 'sku, price, special_price, ' . implode(', ', $tier);

foreach($arr as $row => $sub){
    foreach($sub as $key => $item){
        // Add items to array (only first three are start)
        $table[$row][$key] = $item;

        // After first three items add empty placeholders with associative keys to tiers array
        if(count($table[$row]) == 3){
            $table[$row] = array_merge($table[$row], array_combine($tier, array_fill(3, $columns, 0)));
        }
    }
}

//For debug purpose, output the CSV header then each row.
echo $header . "\n";
foreach($table as $row){
    echo implode(', ', $row) . "\n";
}

//var_dump($tier, $header, $table);
```

https://3v4l.org/lJnXL

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I was looking for.